# How to change Custom Object Property Values while doing foreach-object loop on Objectarray

Tags: powershell

```
function DeleteADUser ()
{
    $AccountObjectCollection | foreach-object {

    if ($_.ADAccountExists -eq $true)
    {
        write-host "User: $($_.ADAccount) found. Deleting..." -ForegroundColor white
        $User = Get-ADUser -server $domain -Identity $_.ADAccount
        Remove-ADUser $User -server $domain -Confirm:$False
        write-host "User: $($_.ADAccount) deleted. Check again..." -ForegroundColor white
            try {
                Get-ADUser  -server $domain -Identity $_.ADAccount | Out-Null
                write-host "User: $($_.ADAccount) exists. Deletion failed!." -ForegroundColor red
        }
                catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityResolutionException] {
                $_.ADAccountExists = $false
                write-host "User: $($_.ADAccount) deleted." -ForegroundColor green
        }
    
    }else {write-host "User: $($_.ADAccount) not found." -ForegroundColor green}

    }
}
```

I have some custom objects in an object array $AccountObjectCollection and try to changes values in my foreach loop on the fly but the line
`$_.ADAccountExists = $false` gets the following exception:
´The property 'ADAccountExists' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.´ Thats odd because I'm literally in an IF Statement that only shoots when this specific Value exists and is set to true so I'm propably doing something wrong here. How can I change the value inside the foreach loop?

Comment: Try to use the .keys method; loop through the keys and then access the object via $AccountObjectCollection[$key]

Comment: Inside your `catch` block, `$_` refers to an exception object, not the current AD account object piped into your `foreach-object` loop.  Thus, it might be best if you used `foreach ($ADObject in $AccountObjectCollection) { ... }` and replaced your instances of `$_` with `$ADObject`.

Comment: @leeharvey1 Thats exactly what I needed to know. Now I understand why it didn't work and fixed it by using your method! Please post your comment as answer, so I can approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `catch` block, `$_` refers to an **exception** object, not the current AD account object piped into your `foreach-object` loop.

Thus, it might be best if you used:

```
foreach ($ADObject in $AccountObjectCollection) {
    # ...
}
```

...and replaced your instances of `$_` inside this `foreach` block with `$ADObject`